# $f \in\mathcal{C}(K,\mathbb{R})$ implies $f(\overline{E})\subseteq\overline{f(E)}$ for every $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ s.t $\overline{E}\subseteq K$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology

Show that if $f \in \mathcal{C}(K,\mathbb{R})$, then $f(\overline{E}) \subseteq \overline{f(E)}$ for every subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that satisfies $\overline{E} \subseteq K$.

My attempt is:

Let $f \in \mathcal{C}(K,\mathbb{R})$ and $y \in f(\overline{E})$. That implies there exists $x \in \overline{E}$ such that $y =f(x)$.

Let $U$ be an open set of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $y \in U$. By definition of continuous function, $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open set of $K$ such that $x \in f^{-1}(U)$.

Therefore, $f^{-1}(U) \cap E \neq \emptyset$ as $x \in \overline{E}$.

Therefore, $\emptyset \neq f\left ( f^{-1}\left ( U \right )\cap E \right ) \subseteq U \cap f(E)$.

That is, $f(\overline{E}) \subseteq \overline{f(E)}$.

I would like to know if there is any mistake in my reasoning. Thanks.

Comment: Your proof is correct and neat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.

Another proof (which doesn't rely on any specifics of the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and thus applies whenever $f : X \to Y$ is a function between any two spaces):

Consider that $f(E) \subseteq \overline{f(E)}$, and therefore $E \subseteq f^{-1}(f(E)) \subseteq f^{-1}(\overline{f(E)})$.

Now since $f$ is continuous and $\overline{f(E)}$ is closed, we have $f^{-1}(\overline{f(E)})$ is closed. Therefore, $\overline{E} \subseteq f^{-1}(\overline{f(E)})$.

Then we have $f(\overline{E}) \subseteq f(f^{-1}(\overline{f(E)})) \subseteq \overline{f(E)}$.